# Add a list of dataGridViewRows to DataGridView

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I have a list of DataGridViewRows like this

List DataGridViewRows list = new List DataGridViewRows ();

And i want to add it to my dataGridView and display it.

Sorry for missing <> in declare List, I'm new in StackOverFlow.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far. Did you get any errors?

Comment: try this => `List<DataGridViewRow> list = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in list)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            }`

Comment: @Jaques I just do not know how to do it in clean way.

Comment: @ershoaib It work but i got some error kind of i shouldn't add it directly. Have any ways to cast DataGridViewRow to DataTableRow ?